# How to rigorously state $P(x)$ is true for all but a finite number of $x$?

Tags: terminology

How to rigorously state that the predicate $P(x)$ is true for all but a finite number of $x\in\mathbb{N}$?

### My Attempt

There is a finite set $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $s\in\mathcal{S}\implies \neg P(x)$ and $s\notin\mathcal{S}, s\in \mathbb{N}\implies P(x)$.

---

But I think there is a much more elegant way to saying the above. Actually, I struggle a lot when formalizing many seemingly super intuitive notion such as the above one.

Comment: What about the statement "$P(x)$ is true for all but finitely many $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is not precise enough as is?

Comment: Oh, it is precise, but it is not formal enough. When statements are not very formal, it is harder to use the fact in proofs. So I always have to make them formal first the use them

Comment: It is very formal, and it shouldn't be harder to use that in a proof, in fact, proofs look **extremely** more elegant if you use *words* instead of chunks of logic symbols.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I know, but it is better for a beginner to write in logic symbols so I really understand what I wrote. I agree that writing in words is more beautiful but it requires you to actually master the logic symbols first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\exists N\forall n(n\gt N\implies P(n))$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it seems like this is more of a equivalent statement rather than the original statement. When we deal with finite or infinite, aren't we always talking about sets? Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: When one writes a formal sentence in first-order logic, what the quantifiers range over is aways understood. One could instead write a sentence of Zermelo-Frankel (or some other) set theory. I chose not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to say that the cardinality of the set of natural numbers for which the predicate is false is finite.

$$\exists n{\in}\Bbb N~\Big(n=\big\lvert\{x{\in}\Bbb N:\neg P(x)\}\big\rvert\Big)
\\ ~ \\
\big(\exists n{\in}\Bbb N\big)\big(\exists^{=n}x{\in} \Bbb N\big)\big(\neg P(x)\big)$$

Something like that.

[The first uses set construction and cardinal measure; the second uses a counting quantifier to say the same thing]